# jQuery using if-else during animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to interact while jQuery runs .animate?
I have a little animation that moves an image from bottom to top.
My animation gets input from outside so that it knows when the animation ends or better at which position it has to stop.

Now I had one little thing to do and that is to see if the animation e.g. reaches more then 70% then my image has to scale down. But this shall only happens when it reaches more then 70% on its distance.
You can compare it with a bottleneck, its getting thinner at the top and so I try to scale my image down.
But I can't find any clue how to do this.

As an example:

Action 1:
  Move 50% -- ok

Action 2:
  Move 90% -- in progress
  -- but at 70% Scale the image down to 50%

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your help, but ... sorry to say that ... I don't get it.
I've tried your solutions but I have always an offset between the top circle and the water:

**[Look here at CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/Tipo/pen/LrGyc)**

Comment: Can you add the .animate method you are talking about so we can get a sense of what you are trying to do with it?

Comment: Maybe two animations, one for the first 70%, the second for the resize and the remaining distance?

Comment: One option would be to use the `step` option to add a function which is called at every step in the animation.  Have a look at the documentation for `animate`.  Another option (assuming linear animation) would be to break it into 2 animations, one animation does the first 70%, the other does the remaining 30 as well as the scaling.

Comment: You can do this with the `step` method, or by using `$.Animation`

Comment: example of animate step and two animations [http://jsfiddle.net/bHbLS/](http://jsfiddle.net/bHbLS/)

Comment: you can try to set the values like this [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIgJa](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIgJa)

Answer (score 1):

As noone else seems to be answering, I'll at least try ?

You can use either the step method, or $.Animation, working with them both is pretty much the same, here's an example with the latter, and examples of how to use the step method should be easy to find here on SO.

```
var elem  = $('#some_element'),
    width = elem.width();

$.Animation( {left: elem.position().left}, 
    {
        left: 500
    }, {
        duration: 2000
    }
).progress(function (e) {
    var start  = e.tweens[0].start, // start position
        end    = e.tweens[0].end,   // end position
        now    = e.tweens[0].now,   // where we are now
        lapsed = Math.ceil(now / end * 100); // calculate percentage

    elem.css('left', now);

    if (lapsed > 70) { // 70% reached
        elem.width(width + ((lapsed-70)*2));  // lets animate width as well
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h98ed/)

Comment: thank you but I tried it to implement and can't get it work.
I edited my post top and added a link to CodePen.io